# jquery one hyperlink should be enabled at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have created two hyper links with Create User and Batch

If one hyper clicked a pop up is being opened , and at the same time when other hyper link (Batch ) should not be opened

(Currently both are being opened )

Please tell me how to resolve this ??

please see my code :

```
var create = dojo.create("div",{
            id:"create_links",
            className:"iconRow1",
            innerHTML:"<a class='popupLink' href='javascript:openDialog()'>Create User</a> <span>|</span><a  href='javascript:openFileDialog()'>Batch </a>"
        }


function openDialog() {


        dojo.byId('create_links').disabled=true;
        $("#create_links").addClass("disabled");

// some code 


    }
```

The other hyper link code is

```
  function openFileDialog() {


       $("#fileuploadfun").attr('title',"Batch");
       $( "#fileuploadfun" ).dialog({ position: 'center' , zIndex: 0, width: 500, show: 'slide', resizable:'false' });

    }

Currently the Dialog bOxes are created in this way :(This is for Batch)

  $("#fileuploadfun").attr('title',"Batch ");
       $( "#fileuploadfun" ).dialog({ position: 'center' , zIndex: 0, width: 500, show: 'slide', resizable:'false' });
```

And the User dialog is created this way :

```
$( "#createUserDialog" ).dialog( "option", "title", 'Create User' );        
$( "#createUserDialog" ).dialog("open");
```

Comment: just a note, use the `onclick` attribute for javascript and set `href="#"`

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make your dialog modal (theres an option for it in the JQuery UI), that way if one is open, the rest of the site can't be used until its closed.

Answer (score 0):

The links cannot be disabled by just any attribute.The way to disable any link is by simply removing the onclick or replacing the href with # or javascript:void(0) to avoid jumping to page top.